# How to handle error using getImage of the Image React-Native component?

Tags: react-native

I can't implement according with the docs at [react native image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#getsize). Can someone help me ?

```
Image.getSize(this.props.data.thumbnail, (width,height) =>{
        const win = Dimensions.get('window')
        const ratio = win.width/width
        this.setState( {
            width: style.width,
            height: height * ratio
        })
    })
```

Comment: What error do You have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a callback for error that you can use to handle the error.

```
 Image.getSize(this.props.data.thumbnail, (width, height) =>
    {
        const win = Dimensions.get('window')
        const ratio = win.width/width
        this.setState({
          width: style.width,
          height: height * ratio
        })
    }, (error) =>
    {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log( error );
    });
```